# Problems with repository pcl17

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I can't download the pcl17 package from this repository: http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/branches/fuerte/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl17/ Has been the repository been changed? How can i download it?

Thank you very much.
Antonio!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58409/problems-with-repository-pcl17/) by [anto1389](https://answers.ros.org/users/3308/anto1389/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2013-03-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PCL just moved to github a few days ago: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl

See [this post](http://www.pcl-developers.org/PCL-moves-to-GIT-td5707770.html) by Jochen Sprickerhof for more information (also on how to access the new git repository by svn). I don't know if this works with the perception_unstable branch for ROS integration though. Can you comment if you tried?

EDIT:
Antonio took this matter to the PCL-users list. The correct path for checking out the perception_unstable branch (= PCL trunk for ROS) from github seems to be https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/tree/fuerte-unstable-devel.

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anto1389](https://answers.ros.org/users/3308/anto1389/) on 2013-03-18**:
It is not working! Building CXX object io/CMakeFiles/pcl_io.dir/src/image_grabber.cpp.o
/pcl/io/src/image_grabber.cpp: In member function ‘bool pcl::ImageGrabberBase::ImageGrabberImpl::getCloudVTK(size_t, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2&, Eigen::Vector4f&, Eigen::Quaternionf&) const.

**Comment by [anto1389](https://answers.ros.org/users/3308/anto1389/) on 2013-03-18**:
/pcl/io/src/image_grabber.cpp:634:34: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘cloud_color.pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZRGBA::header.std_msgs::Header_std::allocator<void >::stamp = timestamp’
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just updated the wiki: http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl17

use: git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl.git -b fuerte-unstable-devel fuerte-unstable-devel

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anto1389](https://answers.ros.org/users/3308/anto1389/) on 2013-03-19**:
I am sorry but there are still error: ../../lib/libpcl_io.so.1.7.0: undefined reference to `ros::TimeBase<ros::Time, ros::Duration>::fromNSec(unsigned long long)' can you tell me how i can download the last version which didn't have errors? Thank you very much!

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-03-19**:
I think this is not a problem of the pcl ros wrapper. You should try a older PCL revision.

**Comment by [anto1389](https://answers.ros.org/users/3308/anto1389/) on 2013-03-19**:
Sorry, for asking you a lot of question, but i don't know how i can do it. Could you tell me, please? Thank you very much!

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-03-19**:
I just try to change the revision, but the make script is broken, I will try to fix it.

**Comment by [anto1389](https://answers.ros.org/users/3308/anto1389/) on 2013-03-19**:
Thank you very very much! Let me know if you can make it! :)

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-03-19**:
See my Pull Request: https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/pulls

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-03-19**:
The last working pcl version is a655516c84a821363dc56ec29f0d6553dfc356fe